# Changing a column's cells to a table based on another columns cells?

Tags: excel, spotfire

What I'm trying to do: in my table there is a column called "Work Request Activity Type" that has cells that describe what kind of "transaction" took place.

These WRAT's they can be split into two types, Financial Actions and Non Financial Actions.

I'm dealing with over 9,000 rows so doing this individually on each row would be a long long process, so what I'm looking to do is somehow create a column where its row cells say Financial or Non financial based on the preceding work request activity type.

Comment: Are the values in the transaction descriptions column standardised?

Comment: I believe so, there are around ~20 different types of transactions and plenty are the same "type"

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could make two separate tables with a list of the Financial WRATs in one and Non-Financial WRATs in the other, then use a something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Fin_WRATs,0)),"Financial Action",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Non_Fin_WRATs,0)),"Non Financial Action","N/A"))` where `Fin_WRATs` is the one column table of  financial WRATs and `Non_Fin_WRATs` is the one column table of non-financial WRATs.  `A1` is the cell which contains the WRAT in the original table.

Comment: your question is quite confusing now. What does is mean "preceding" in your context? Is it about Excel or Spotfire? Please post some sample data with desired categorization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is an additional column that specifies whether the type of WRAT is financial or non-financial? If that is right, you can do that as follows:

In Spotfire you can add columns to your data table via `Insert > Calculated Column`.

With a simple if-statement in the calculated column you can specify all the transactions as either financial or non-financial actions.

For example:

```
If([YourColumn]=="type1" OR [YourColumn] =="type2" OR [YourColumn] == "type3, etc. , "Financial, "Non-Financial" )
```

Alternatively, you could also do the same in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'in' to shorten your cases:

```
if([YourColumn] in ("type1","type2","type3"),"Financial","Non-Financial")
```

Take a look at the ~= operator as well. Very powerful to find text within text. Works like wildcards:

```
if([yourColumn] ~= "type","Financial","Non-Financial")
```